# AngularJS app Crashing using parameter in $resource query()

Tags: angularjs

I made this simple factory returning a $resource:

```
app.factory('OusService', function ($resource,BASE_API) {
    var res;
    res = $resource(BASE_API+'/ou/:ouId',null,{
       update: {
          method: 'PUT' // this method issues a PUT request
       }
   });
   return res;
});
```

Then I'm using that $resource in a controller called 'navCtrl' :

```
app.controller('navCtrl', ["$scope","$localStorage","OusService", function ($scope,$localStorage,OusService) {

   var navOrg = $localStorage.navOrg;
   OusService.query({ouId: navOrg.ou_id}).$promise.then(function(data){
         console.log(data); 
   }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
}]);
```

That code is completely crashing but if I remove '{ouId: navOrg.ou_id}' the code is executed but the query doesn't contain the required parameter. I tried without a promise, with a callback, withtout a callback nor a promise. The code is always crashing with parameter.

I also tried defining default parameters in the factory.

Error :

```
TypeError: V is not a function
at http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:34:14237
at forEach (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:10:14316)
at C.setUrlParams (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:34:14122)
at Function.l.(anonymous function) [as query] (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:34:12722)
at new <anonymous> (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/controllers/navCtrl.js:13:16)
at Object.invoke (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:11:16221)
at extend.instance (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:13:8182)
at nodeLinkFn (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:12:11139)
at compositeLinkFn (http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:12:2680)
at http://10.0.0.145:8003/layout1/assets/js/app.min.js:12:1389 <nav data-ng-include=" 'assets/views/partials/nav.html' " class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

EDIT :

I updated angularjs from 1.5.7 to 1.5.11 and the problem has been resolved.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

to use like this .. have you tried something like:

```
app.factory('OusService', function ($resource,BASE_API) {
    var res;
    res = $resource(BASE_API+'/ou/:ouId',{'@ouId':ouId},{
       query: {
          method: 'GET',isArray:true // or false if return an object
       }
   });
   return res;
});
```

And then use it as you want

```
app.controller('navCtrl', ["$scope","$localStorage","OusService", function ($scope,$localStorage,OusService) {

   var navOrg = $localStorage.navOrg;
   OusService.query({ouId: navOrg.ou_id}).$promise.then(function(data){
         console.log(data); 
   }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
   });
}]);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but unfortunately it throw the same error. I just don't get it. I just tested with "invalid parameter" like .query({test:'testing'}) and it doesn't crash but it doesn't send any parameter to the API. Is crashing if I try to send "ouId".

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the `$resource` `query` method accepts an argument. Rather, it returns an array of results. If you want to pass an `id` in I would suggest using `get`

```
OusService.get({ouId: navOrg.ou_id}).$promise.then(function(data){
  console.log(data); 
}, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Also, try updating your resource to the following:

```
app.factory('OusService', ['$resource', 'BASE_API',
  function($resource, BASE_API) {
    var res;
    res = $resource(BASE_API + '/ou/:ouId', {ouId: @ouId}, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
    return res;
  }
]);
```

The key changes to note being: `{ouId: @ouId}` as well as `['$resource', 'BASE_API',`

Comment: @SRUEL, updated my answer. I think this may solve it.

Comment: Now my grunt task to uglify is crashing : Unexpected character '@'. I will try to remove that task.

Comment: @SRUEL, that most likely has to do with Dependency Injection. I updated the answer again to, hopefully, protect against that issue.

Comment: doesn't work. probably something wrong elsewhere... Thank you I will continue to troubleshoot.

Comment: Upgraded from angularJS 1.5.7 to 1.5.11 and the problem has been resolved.